# Sprite image rendering incorrectly on android tablet

Tags: animation, android-layout, sprite, android

I have a sprite animation in my app and it's working fine for standard phone sized screens but whenever I put it on a tablet the animation gets glitchy and doesn't look right at all.  I think it has something to do with the height and widths of the image.  I've tried setting them as dp and sp but they still won't render right on the tablet.

Here's my animation xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="100dp" >

    <view
        android:id="@+id/animation"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        class="com.scale.AndroidAnimation" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my animation code

```
public class AndroidAnimation extends View{
    private Bitmap mAnimation;
    private Rect mSRectangle;
    private int mNoOfFrames;
    private int mCurrentFrame;
    private int mSpriteHeight;
    private int mSpriteWidth;

    public AndroidAnimation(Context context, AttributeSet aSet) {
        super(context, aSet);        
        mSRectangle = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
        mCurrentFrame = 0;
    }

    public void init(Bitmap theBitmap, int Height, int Width, int theFrameCount) {
        mAnimation = theBitmap;
        mSpriteHeight = Height;
        mSpriteWidth = Width;
        mSRectangle.top = 0;
        mSRectangle.bottom = mSpriteHeight;
        mSRectangle.left = 0;
        mSRectangle.right = mSpriteWidth;
        mNoOfFrames = theFrameCount;
        mCurrentFrame = 0;
   }

   public void update() {
       mCurrentFrame++;
       mCurrentFrame %= mNoOfFrames;   
       mSRectangle.left = mCurrentFrame * mSpriteWidth;
       mSRectangle.right = mSRectangle.left + mSpriteWidth;      
   }

   @Override
   public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       super.onDraw(canvas);
       Rect dest = new Rect(0, 0, mSpriteWidth, mSpriteHeight);   
       canvas.drawBitmap(mAnimation, mSRectangle, dest, null);
   }   
}
```

Where I initialize it

```
anim = (AndroidAnimation) findViewById(R.id.animation);
anim.init(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.connecting_sprite), 300, 170, 3);
mHandler.removeCallbacks(myTimerTask);
mHandler.postDelayed(myTimerTask, 300);
```

My handler that progresses it

```
public void run() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(myTimerTask);

    if (mCurrScreen == WAITING_SCREEN) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(myTimerTask, 300);
    }

    anim.update();
    anim.invalidate();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is good way to design seperate layout for tablet.Create layout-xlarge folder in res and put your new layout animation.xml file which is optimized for tablet screen.